# Find a key on a multidimensional associative array and modify the array structure (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to modify a few things about a multidimensional array.
First, I need to convert a key that contains an array into an element of that same array. In order to do that, I need to find the key's name. The problem here is that the key keeps changing it's name. The key I'm gonna base the modifications on is called "grupo*" and a number.

Here's an example of the array (extracted using the print_r() PHP function):

```
Array
(
    [codigo] => 21201
    [nombre] => CALCULO INTEGRAL
    [creditos] => 3
    [grupo8] => Array
        (
            [horario] => Array
                (
                    [martes] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => G-216
                                    [1] => G-216
                                )
                            [horaInicio] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1600
                                    [1] => 1700
                                )
                            [horaFin] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1700
                                    [1] => 1800
                                )
                        )
                    [jueves] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => C-102
                                    [1] => C-102
                                )
                            [horaInicio] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1600
                                    [1] => 1700
                                )
                            [horaFin] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1700
                                    [1] => 1800
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
Array
(
    [codigo] => 21202
    [nombre] => FISICA MECANICA
    [creditos] => 4
    [grupo1] => Array
        (
            [horario] => Array
                (
                    [lunes] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Lab B-207
                                    [1] => Lab B-207
                                )
                            [horaInicio] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1300
                                    [1] => 1400
                                )
                            [horaFin] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1400
                                    [1] => 1500
                                )
                        )
                    [martes] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => G-110
                                    [1] => G-110
                                )
                            [horaInicio] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1300
                                    [1] => 1400
                                )
                            [horaFin] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1400
                                    [1] => 1500
                                )
                        )
                    [jueves] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Agora 101
                            [horaInicio] => 1300
                            [horaFin] => 1400
                        )
                )
        )
)
Array
(
    [codigo] => 21203
    [nombre] => ALGEBRA LINEAL
    [creditos] => 3
    [grupo13] => Array
        (
            [horario] => Array
                (
                    [lunes] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => B-108
                            [horaInicio] => 1100
                            [horaFin] => 1200
                        )
                    [viernes] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => B-107
                                    [1] => B-107
                                )
                            [horaInicio] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1000
                                    [1] => 1100
                                )
                            [horaFin] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1100
                                    [1] => 1200
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
Array
(
    [codigo] => 21304
    [nombre] => PROGRAMACION ORIENTADA A OBJETOS
    [creditos] => 3
    [grupo4] => Array
        (
            [horario] => Array
                (
                    [miercoles] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => B209 lab
                                    [1] => B209 lab
                                    [2] => B209 lab
                                )
                            [horaInicio] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1400
                                    [1] => 1500
                                    [2] => 1600
                                )
                            [horaFin] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1500
                                    [1] => 1600
                                    [2] => 1700
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
Array
(
    [codigo] => 275201
    [nombre] => MATEMATICAS DISCRETAS
    [creditos] => 2
    [grupo2] => Array
        (
            [horario] => Array
                (
                    [jueves] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => A-203
                                    [1] => A-203
                                )
                            [horaInicio] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1100
                                    [1] => 1200
                                )
                            [horaFin] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1200
                                    [1] => 1300
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
Array
(
    [codigo] => MAKE
    [nombre] => MARKETING ELECTRONICO
    [creditos] => 2
    [grupo1] => Array
        (
            [horario] => Array
                (
                    [viernes] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => G-219
                                    [1] => G-219
                                )
                            [horaInicio] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1200
                                    [1] => 1300
                                )
                            [horaFin] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1300
                                    [1] => 1400
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

As you can see, the key [grupo*] keeps changing number, and it can be a 1 or 2 digit number. The only thing I know is that such a key contains an array.

I need to do the same thing to one of the arrays inside, the one that is a weekday.

Here is an example of how the array is supposed to look (as JSON):

```
{
    "codigo": "21201",
    "nombre": "CALCULO INTEGRAL",
    "creditos": "3",
    "grupo": "8",
    "horario": [
        {
            "dia": "martes",
            "salon": [
                "G-216",
                "G-216"
            ],
            "horaInicio": [
                "1600",
                "1700"
            ],
            "horaFin": [
                "1700",
                "1800"
            ]
        },
        {
            "dia": "jueves",
            "salon": [
                "C-102",
                "C-102"
            ],
            "horaInicio": [
                "1600",
                "1700"
            ],
            "horaFin": [
                "1700",
                "1800"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The weekday keeps changing, so I have a similar problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

old array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [codigo] => MAKE
            [nombre] => MARKETING ELECTRONICO
            [creditos] => 2
            [grupo12] => Array
                (
                    [horario] => Array
                        (
                            [lunes] => Array
                                (
                                    [salon] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => G-219
                                            [1] => G-219
                                        )

                                    [horaInicio] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 1200
                                            [1] => 1300
                                        )

                                    [horaFin] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 1300
                                            [1] => 1400
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [codigo] => MAKE
            [nombre] =>  PROGRAMACION ORIENTADA A OBJETOS
            [creditos] => 3
            [grupo13] => Array
                (
                    [horario] => Array
                        (
                            [viernes] => Array
                                (
                                    [salon] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => B209 lab
                                            [1] => B209 lab
                                        )

                                    [horaInicio] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 1400
                                            [1] => 1500
                                        )

                                    [horaFin] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 1600
                                            [1] => 1700
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

All in one line of code

```
foreach ($data as $k => $groups) {
    foreach ($groups as $v => $group) {
        // find the match 
        if (preg_match('/^grupo*/', $v)) {
            // split the key into key and value.
            $key = substr($v, 0, 5);
            $value = substr($v, 5);
            // push the key into the array and assign its value 
            $data[$k][$key] = $value;
            // loop through the horario array
            foreach ($group['horario'] as $d => $dia) {
                // push dia as key into horario array assign the key $d as value
                $group['horario'][] = ['dia'=>$d,$dia];
                //push the sub arrays into the new horario array 
                //foreach ($dia as $a => $arr) {
                //  $group['horario'][$a] = $arr;
                //}
                //unset the old horario array
                unset($group['horario'][$d]);
            }
            // push the new horario in the main array
            $data[$k]['horario'] = $group['horario'];
            // unset the old grupo array
            unset($data[$k][$v]);

        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
[
    {
        "codigo": "MAKE",
        "nombre": "MARKETING ELECTRONICO",
        "creditos": 2,
        "grupo": "12",
        "horario": [
            {
                "dia": "lunes",
                "0": {
                    "salon": [
                        "G-219",
                        "G-219"
                    ],
                    "horaInicio": [
                        "1200",
                        "1300"
                    ],
                    "horaFin": [
                        "1300",
                        "1400"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "dia": "martes",
                "0": {
                    "salon": [
                        "G-219",
                        "G-219"
                    ],
                    "horaInicio": [
                        "1200",
                        "1300"
                    ],
                    "horaFin": [
                        "1300",
                        "1400"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Almost perfect, you missed a ')' in the preg_match function. This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: @HaPK You are welcome, I will add the missing parentheses. :).

Comment: there's another bug, note that sometimes the "horario" array has several different days, but your code only adds the last day in the array. I tried to fix it by adding a simple `$dias[]= $group['horario'];` inside the `group['horario']` foreach loop and later assigning it like `$data[$k]['horario']=$dias;` but it didn't work.

Comment: had to change `['dia'=>$d,$dia]` for `array('dia'=>$d,$dia)`, but it seems it works now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is:

```
Array
(
    [codigo] => 21201
    [nombre] => CALCULO INTEGRAL
    [creditos] => 3
    [grupo8] => Array
        (
            [horario] => Array
                (
                    [martes] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => G-216
                                    [1] => G-216
                                )
                            [horaInicio] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1600
                                    [1] => 1700
                                )
                            [horaFin] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1700
                                    [1] => 1800
                                )
                        )
                    [jueves] => Array
                        (
                            [salon] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => C-102
                                    [1] => C-102
                                )
                            [horaInicio] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1600
                                    [1] => 1700
                                )
                            [horaFin] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1700
                                    [1] => 1800
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

You can get all keys of it with `array_keys`:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$needed_key = false;
foreach ($keys as $k) {
    if (strpos($k, 'grupo') !== false) {
        $needed_key = $k;
        break;
    }
}

if ($needed_key) {
    $arr['horario'] = $arr[$needed_key]['horario'];
    $arr['grupo'] = substr($needed_key, 5);
    unset($arr[$needed_key]);
}
```